# How to save a document with a dynamic id into Cloud Firestore? Always changing

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, addition

I am using Cloud Firestore as my database
This is my form codes on my webpage that creates a new document into my Cloud Firestore collection called "esequiz". So how do I code it in such a way that it always plus 1 to the number of documents there are in the database? And also set a limit to having the amount of documents inside the database

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
db.collection('esequiz').add({
    question: form.question.value,
    right: form.right.value,
    wrong: form.wrong.value
});
form.question.value = '';
form.right.value = '';
form.wrong.value = '';
});
```

It currently works but it will show up as an auto generated ID. How do I make it carry on from the numbers, like as my current documents? When i save I would like it to read the current last document id, OR simply count the number of documents, then just + 1
[image]

Insight from Andrei Cusnir, counting documents in Cloud Firestore is not supported.

Now I am trying Andrei's approach 2, to query documents in descending order, then using .limit to retrieve the first one only.

**UPDATED**

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
let query = db.collection('esequiz');
let getvalue = query.orderBy('id', 'desc').limit(1).get();
let newvalue = getvalue + 1;
db.collection('esequiz').doc(newvalue).set({
    question: form.question.value,
    right: form.right.value,
    wrong: form.wrong.value
});
form.question.value = '';
form.right.value = '';
form.wrong.value = '';
});
```

No more error, but instead, the code below returns [object Promise]

> let getvalue = query.orderBy('id', 'desc').limit(1).get();

So when my form saves, it saves as [object Promise]1, which I don't know why it is like this. Can someone advise me on how to return the document id value instead of [object Promise]

I think it is because I did specify to pull the document id as the value, how do I do so?
[image]

**UPDATED: FINAL SOLUTION**

Played around with the codes from Andrei, and here are the final codes that works. Much thanks to Andrei!

```
let query = db.collection('esequiz');
//let getvalue = query.orderBy('id', 'desc').limit(1).get();
//let newvalue = getvalue + 1;    
query.orderBy('id', 'desc').limit(1).get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
        var newID = documentSnapshot.id;
        console.log(`Found document at ${documentSnapshot.ref.path}`);
        console.log(`Document's ID: ${documentSnapshot.id}`);
        var newvalue = parseInt(newID, 10) + 1;
        var ToString = ""+ newvalue;
        db.collection('esequiz').doc(ToString).set({
            id: newvalue,
            question: form.question.value,
            right: form.right.value,
            wrong: form.wrong.value
        });
    });
    });
```

Comment: It's not `.length()` but `.length` because it's not a function but a property. So try with `let x = db.collection('esequiz').doc.length;`

Comment: @johannchopin hi, tried the .length as mentioned but it shown up a new error instead, updated in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are adding data to the Cloud Firestore and each new document will have as name an incremental number.

If you query all the documents and then count how many are of them, then you are going to end up with many document reads as the database increases. Don't forget that Cloud Firestore is charging per document Read and Write, therefore if you have 100 documents and you want to add new document with ID: 101, then with the approach of first reading all of them and then counting them will cost you 100 Reads and then 1 Write. The next time it will cost you 101 Reads and 1 Write. And it will go on as your database increases.

The way I see is from two different approaches:

#### Approach 1:

You can have a single document that will hold all the information of the database and what the next name should be.

e.g.

```
The structure of the database:
esequiz:
        0: 
          last_document: 2
        1: 
          question: "What is 3+3?
          right: "6"
          wrong: "0"
        2: 
          question: "What is 2+3?
          right: "5"
          wrong: "0"
```

So the process will go as follows:

1. Read document "/esequiz/0" **Counts as 1 READ**
2. Create new document with ID: `last_document + 1` **Counts as 1 WRITE**
3. Update the document that holds the information: `last_document = 3;` **Counts as 1 WRITE**

This approach cost you 1 READ and 2 WRITES to the database.

#### Approach 2:

You can load only the last document from the database and get it's ID.

e.g.

```
The structure of the database (Same as before, but without the additional doc):
esequiz:
        1: 
          question: "What is 3+3?
          right: "6"
          wrong: "0"
        2: 
          question: "What is 2+3?
          right: "5"
          wrong: "0"
```

So the process will go as follows:

1. Read the last document using the approach described in [Order and limit data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) documentation. So you can use `direction=firestore.Query.DESCENDING` with combination of `limit(1)` which will give you the last document. **Counts as 1 READ**
2. Now you know the ID of the loaded document so you can create new document with ID: that will use the loaded value and increase it by 1. **Counts as 1 WRITE**

This approach cost you 1 READ and 1 WRITE in total to the database.

---

I hope that this information was helpful and it resolves your issue. Currently counting documents in Cloud Firestore is not supported.

**UPDATE**

In order for the sorting to work, you will also have to include the id as a filed of the document that so you can be able to order based on it. I have tested the following example and it is working for me:

Structure of database:

```
esequiz:
        1: 
          id: 1
          question: "What is 3+3?
          right: "6"
          wrong: "0"
        2: 
          id:2
          question: "What is 2+3?
          right: "5"
          wrong: "0"
```

As you can see the ID is set the same as the document's ID.

Now you can query all the documents and order based on that filed. At the same time you can only retrieve the last document from the query:

```
const {Firestore} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const firestore = new Firestore();

async function getLastDocument(){

    let query = firestore.collection('esequiz');

    query.orderBy('id', 'desc').limit(1).get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
        console.log(`Found document at ${documentSnapshot.ref.path}`);
        console.log(`Document's ID: ${documentSnapshot.id}`);
    });
    });

}

OUTPUT:
Found document at esequiz/2
Document's ID: 2
```

Then you can take the ID and increase it by 1 to generate the name for your new document!

**UPDATE 2**

So, the initial question is about "How to store data in the Cloud Firestore with documents having incremental ID", at the moment you are facing issues of setting up Firestore with you project. Unfortunately, the new raised questions should be discussed in another Stackoverflow post as they have nothing to do with the logic of having incremental IDs for the document and it is better to keep one issue per question, to give better community support for members that are looking for a solution about particular issues. Therefore, I will try to help you, in this post, to execute a simple Node.js script and resolve the initial issue, which is storing to Cloud Firestore documents with incremental IDs. Everything else, on how to setup this in your project and how to have this function in your page, should be addressed in additional question, where you also will need to provide as much information as possible about the Framework you are using, the project setup etc.

So, lets make a simple app.js work with the logic described above:

1. Since you have Cloud Firestore already working, this means that you already have Google Cloud Platform project (where the Firestore relies) and the proper APIs already enabled. *Otherwise it wouldn't be working*.
2. Your guide in this tutorial is the [Cloud Firestore: Node.js Client](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/) documentation. It will help you to understand all the methods you can use with the Firestore Node.js API. You can find helpful links for adding, reading, querying documents and many more operations. (*I will post entire working code later in this steps. I just shared the link so you know where to look for additional features*)
3. Go to [Google Cloud Console Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard) page. You should login with your Google account where your project with the Firestore database is setup.
4. On top right corner you should see 4 buttons and your profile picture. The first button is the **Activate Cloud Shell**. This will open a terminal on the bottom of the page with linux OS and Google Cloud SDK already install. There you can interact with your resources within GCP projects and test your code locally before using it in your projects.
5. After clicking that button, you will notice that the terminal will open in the bottom of your page.
6. To make sure that you are properly authenticated we will set up the project and authenticate the account again, even if it is already done by default. So first execute `$ gcloud auth login`
7. On the prompted question type `Y` and hit enter
8. Click on the generated link and authenticate your account on the prompted window
9. Copy the generated string back to the terminal and hit enter. Now you should be properly authenticated.
10. Then setup the project that contains Cloud Firestore database with the following command: `$ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID`. Now you are ready to build a simple app.js script and execute it.
11. Create a new app.js file: `nano app.js`
12. Inside paste my code example that can be found in this [GitHub link](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Firestore/Node.js/create_document_with_incremental_id.js). It contains fully working example and many comments explaining each part therefore it is better that it is shared through GitHub link and not pasted here. Without doing any modifications, this code will execute exactly what you are trying to do. I have tested it my self and it is working.
13. Execute the script as: `node app.js`
14. This will give you the following error:

    > Error: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/firestore'

Since we are importing the library `@google-cloud/firestore` but haven't installed it yet.

15. Install `@google-cloud/firestore` library as follows: `$ npm i @google-cloud/firestore`. Described in [DOC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore).
16. Execute the script again: `$ node app.js`.
17. You should see e.g. `Document with ID: 3 is written.`
18. If you execute again, you should see e.g. `Document with ID: 4 is written.`

All those changes should appear in your Cloud Firestore database as well. As you can see it is loading the ID of the last document, it is creating a new ID and then it creates a new document with the given arguments, while using the new generated ID as document name. This is exactly what the initial issue was about.

So I have shared with you the full code that works and does exactly what you are trying to do. Unfortunately, the other newly raised issues, should be addressed in another Stackoverflow post, as they have nothing to do with the initial issue, which is "How to create documents with incremental ID". I recommend you to follow the steps and have a working example and then try to implement the logic to your project. However, if you are still facing any issues with how to setup Firestore in your project then you can ask another question. After that you can combine both solutions and you will have working app!

Good luck!

Comment: Understanding is correct, will try it out now. Thanks for enlightening!

Comment: Hey @Andrei Cusnir, I tried your codes like the above but it still couldnt work, error is firestore is not defined in the line "direction = firestore.Query.DESCENDING"

But i modified to firestore to "db.collection('esequiz'), it then says "Cannot read property "DESCENDING" of undefined"

Comment: @Basir La. I am sorry for the confusion, apparently you also need to have one more field to sort based on it. Please take a look at my UPDATED answer as this code works for me as expected.

Comment: I've been trying but been getting some errors upon some codes, for example the first const, i put it in my app.js and it says it cannot be imported outside the module, making firestore in "let query = firestore.collection('esequiz');" being undefined. I also tried modifying the codes as shown in the UPDATED CODES in my question, but i still get error sayingrequires first argument to be of type non empty string but it was: a custom promise object @Andrei Cusnir

Comment: Sorry but I am still a student and unsure of which codes fit where, but I am currently writing them on an app.js

Comment: How do i add this function into my form, because the sequence of flow would be just, user fills in form, clicks button and it will save into my firestore

Comment: Hello, @Basir La. The initial issue is how to create documents with incremental IDs in Firestore. As now you are having issues setting up properly Firestore with your project and displaying the data with forms, I believe it should be better that those new questions to be addressed in a new Stackoverflow question. I have thought updated my answer with **UPDATE 2**. It gives step by step explanation on how to execute a simple node.js script that will add new documents with incremental IDs. The steps are tested and should be working

Comment: Oh, I manipulated the codes into my form button codes, and it worked! I did not use your async function lines. Thank you so much @Andrei Cusnir !! I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the way you are trying to get the length of the collection is right and I am entirely not sure what is the best way to get that either. Because the method you are trying to implement will cost you a lot more as you are trying to read all the records of the collection.

But there can be alternatives to get the number you require.

1. Start storing the ID in the record and make the query with limit 1 and a descending sort on ID.
2. Store the latest number in another collection and increment that every time you create a new record, And fetch the same whenever needed.

These methods might fail if concurrent requests are being made without transactions.

Comment: What would be a way to just read the number of documents in the collection?

Comment: This will work for small collections
`db.collection('...').get().then(snap => {
   size = snap.size // will return the collection size
});`

I suggest that you go through the following article.
[https://config9.com/apps/firebase/firebase-firestore-collection-count/]

Comment: Thanks! Will take a look at the article. Appreciate it

Comment: It was not able to count the number of documents inside and it isntead returned [object Promise], in the database it showed up as [object Promise] 1, instead of an integer as intended.
Also the article page was not found when I tried to look into it

Comment: I am using a small collections, like as shown in the image above, where there is only 3 documents

Comment: This is an Async call, you will have to either use 'await' to wait for the data or you should use a callback. try running the code I shared in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes i am responding to code you have shared above, I tried it and it resulted as [object Promise] 1 when saved

Comment: My Bad: https://config9.com/apps/firebase/firebase-firestore-collection-count/
the above link included ']' at the end. Go to the link.
Which library are you using to connect to firestore? I will try and replicate what you are doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206512/discussion-between-saurav-suman-and-basir-la).

Comment: Hi @Saurav Suman, sorry for replying so late. Would love to continue the discussion in the chat if possible