# How do I make css affect list item in .js only and not in my .html

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I am currently using Visual Studio Code to develop a web application and I have 3 files
index.html, styles.css and app.js
Currently in my html, I am creating a navbar based on **ul and li**

whereas in my app.js, I am also using ul li to create a list to show values pulled from my database.

My issue is, in my css, this styles meant for my app.js only, is appearing for my index.html **li** items as well. I understand why it is happening, but I am unsure of how to fix this.

```
li{
padding: 20px;
background: #f6f6f6;
font-size: 20px;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
position: relative;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
height: 80px;
}
```

As shown, this li css is affecting the li inside of the navbar, and the li in the list displayed on the body

Would appreciate any help, thanks.

[image]

> Here is my html navbar codes

```
    <header>
        <img class = "logo" src="images/logo.jpg" height = "50">
        <h1 style="color:rgb(0, 0, 0);font-size:30px">Physics Tutor Portal</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul class = "nav_links">

                <li><a href="#"><button>Unknown Questions</button></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><button>Manage Quiz</button></a></li class = "test">
                <li><a href="#"><button>Quiz Statistics</button></a></li class = "test">
                <li><a href="#"><button>Feedbacks</button></a></li class = "test">
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Assign a class to items in navbar (ul, li, a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`css` is always applied to `html`, you can only design or change the color of a html tag.

Your `javascript` file will generate a list `li` in your case but that just means that he's gonna be added to the current `html` so it's potentially going to be altered by your `css`.

And this is indeed the case because you stipulate a rule with `li {}` which means that all the `li`on your page will be affected, even the ones generated by `javascript`.

To avoid this you will need to update your `html` structure to make your `css` more precise. For example: your generated list will be encapsulated in a `ul` tag, the list is here to 'manage the quizz' (if I understood you correctly). So you can simply add an `id` to this `ul` like `<ul id="quizzManager">`. You will be able able now to write `css` only for `li` who are children from a `ul` with the id `quizzManager` just like that:

```css
ul#quizzManager li {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  height: 80px;
}
```

In this case, all `li` that are not in a `ul#quizzManager` will not be affected by this `css`.

Comment: Great explanation, totally understood. Just that the above li codes, are meant for the javascript file instead of the html, how should I edit this then?

Comment: Thanks for the help @johannchopin. It worked and great explanations, appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @BasirLa Not a problem ;)

Comment: If possible, could you help me take a look at one of my other questions? Its relating to some functions in my app.js codes 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59857586/how-to-save-a-document-with-a-dynamic-id-into-cloud-firestore-always-changing